# Failed to Load swf on a facebook iframe application

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook

I'm currently learning how to make facebook apps, and I've hit a problem.

Usually when I make flash applications, I can use the index.html and run the swf from a webserver.
However, I tried to make a facebook iFrame app using the same setup, all I get is the Alternative Content Text.

Any experienced flash/facebook developer help would be greatly appreciated by this newbie.

Below is what happen to my tutorial app.

http://apps.facebook.com/jeffcheetest/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have filled the field "App Namespace" in the Developer Application Settings? I think it could be the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using FBML?  If so, it may be easier to switch to iframe in order to have the swf work in the .html page as you expect it to work.  Otherwise, you will need to implement your swf through fbml tags or fbjs code.